# Featured on Google- Is it legal?

Tags: copyright, trademark

This is not a duplicate of [Is it legal to display third-party logos as part of “As featured in” on sites/printed ads without their consent?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5032/is-it-legal-to-display-third-party-logos-as-part-of-as-featured-in-on-sites-pr), but related to this.

I have a website. If my websites was mentioned on popular site, I put a small note on my website "Featured on ThatCompanyLogo"....

Anyone can find our website using Google. I mean we can be find on Google search results...

So if we mentioned "Featured on Google", is it a illegal work?

Comment: Maybe you should say something like "To find me on Google, type 'law stackexchange'." This use of Google's trademark does not imply that Google is endorsing your site or products.

Comment: While a general discussion of this question may be informative, details may vary from one jurisdiction to another.  Something might be perfectly acceptable in Indonesia but forbidden in Kenya, or vice versa.